# Why can't I access my WWW prefix domain with CDN?

Tags: web-server, domain, web, cdn

I know this kind of question have existing solutions , but none of them solve my problems

once I enter my web with prefix WWW , it displays such 403 error:

[403 error demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/215Ic.png)

This is my Domain parse setting:

[Domain parse setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGSJl.png)

And this is my CDN setting screenshot, my server is Aliyun cloud.
[CDN setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqyd1.png)

This is my Nginx configuration screenshot:

[Nginx configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz5Zz.png)

as you can see , I configure `www.example.com` and `example.com` in my Nginx , I also add CDN CNAME to `www.example.com` and `example.com` ,  I can access `example.com` but cant access `www.example.com`.

and I ping both of them , they can response normally with CDN domain address but different IP address,
Here is the Ping screenshot

[Ping screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEmrk.png)

But I just can't access `www.example.com` in browser , it is so wired.

BTW,this is my whole Nginx configure

```
mysite_nginx.conf

 the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django_ {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket

    server 127.0.0.1:8005; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

 configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name www.labtine.com labtine.com # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/cg_log/CG_log/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/cg_log/CG_log/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {


        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8003;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole NGINX config?

Comment: @Stuggi yeah , i have posted it